# PHP Convert Number to Date

Tags: php, date

I have the following numbers (actually I have to get these from a text file enclosed in " ").
How do I turn these into a date?
101887 (turns to October 18, 1987)
022500 (turns to February 25, 2000)

Comment: `$dto = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdy', '101887');` Then you can format it however you want using the format() method, [e.g](https://3v4l.org/UKp4E)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by parsing the string and then feeding it into `strtotime` and then `date`:

```
$str = '101887';
$str = $str[0].$str[1].'/'.$str[2].$str[3].'/'.$str[4].$str[5];
echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime($str));
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to upvote if you found it useful ;)